# How to query all child then take root name in firebasedatabase?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an Android app. I want to publish people's ads. But I have stuck one problem. I can not query all child. I have 2 type info. These are categories that selected and user's name ( @ before words.) I want to publish all people ads according to the category.  But I can not reach all child and I do not know to do it. By the way; When I reached all child. I do not know how to reach their root.  Unfortunately: I can not explain my problem correctly.
So that: I show you with images my problem.

Here is my firebasedatabase how to seeing :

[image]

For example : I am seeking "Kadın Sağlığı".

[image]

After I need to find these roots  :

[image]

Lastly here is my code :

```
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        uzmanlar_firebaseDatabase = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Uzman/");
uzmanlar_firebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        uzman_kisiler_ilanlar_array.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


            String child = ds.getKey();
            uzman_kisiler_ilanlar_array.add(child);

            for (int i = 0; i < uzman_kisiler_ilanlar_array.size(); i++) {

              Log.i(TAG, "uzmanlarım: "  + uzman_kisiler_ilanlar_array.get(i).toString() + " " + uzman_kisiler_ilanlar_array.size() );

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
 for (String s: uzman_kisiler_ilanlar_array
         ) {

        uzmanlar_yetenekler_firebaseDatabase = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Uzman/" + s + "/" +  "yetenekler/" );
        uzmanlar_yetenekler_firebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()

                        ) {
                    String ss = ds.getValue().toString();

                    Log.i(TAG, "yetenekl: "  + ss  );

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing child with root, you probably meant parent of the corresponding child node.

> I think you want to get the parent `DatabaseReference` from the node you are currently listening. Please check out [DatabaseReference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference).

Calling `getParent()` or `getRoot()`  from the `dataSnapshot.getRef()` will probably do the job.

*As stated from the docs:*

> `getRoot()` returns a reference to the root location of this Firebase Database.
>
> `getParent()` A DatabaseReference to the parent location, or null if this instance references the root location

Edit:

```
uzmanlar_firebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        uzman_kisiler_ilanlar_array.clear();
        DatabaseReference root = dataSnapshot.getRef().getRoot();
        // Now you got the root
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please solve my problem? And give me answer with codes.